# Tabla con índices de PHP a JSON

Tags: php, json

Estoy recogiendo valores de una tabla en MySQL con PHP para conseguir un array en JSON, hasta ahora lo consigo. Sin embargo intento conseguir una tabla de registros con la siguiente estructura:

```
          | día      | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    Abril | conteo 1 | a b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ 
          | conteo 2 | b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ o
    ______________________________________________________
          | día      | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    Mayo  | conteo 1 | a b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ 
          | conteo 2 | b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ o
    ______________________________________________________
          | día      | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    Junio | conteo 1 | a b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ 
    ______| conteo 2 | b c d e f g h y  j  k  l  m  n ñ o
```

Hasta ahora estoy recogiendo los parámetros de MySQL Así:

```
     $clave = "1002";
     $resulRB4 = ClaseTike::consultaListado($clave);
     $bucle_RB4 = $resulRB4[0];
     $contadorRB4 = count($bucle_RB4);
     $arrayRB4 = [];
     foreach($bucle_RB4 as $itemRB4):
        $arrayRB4[]= array(
            "id"        => $itemRB4['id'],
            "dia"       => $itemRB4['dia'],
            "conteo1"   => $itemRB4['conteo1'],
            "conteo2"   => $itemRB4['conteo2'], 
            "mes"       => $itemRB4['mes']
            );
     endforeach;
     $arrayRB4JSON = json_encode($arrayRB4);
     echo $arrayRB4JSON;
```

Desde la Query:

```
    public static function consultaListado($clave){
      $conexion = new conexion();
      $consulta = $conexion->prepare("
      SELECT * FROM ". self::TABLA ." a
      WHERE clave_comun = :clave ORDER BY a.id ASC");
      $consulta->bindParam(':clave', $clave);
      $consulta->execute();
      $registros = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $total = $conexion->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
      return [ $registros ];
    }
```

La estructura de la tabla es del tipo:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dia` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conteo1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conteo2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave_comun` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Es posible que necesite crear una matriz multidimensional, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

EDITO: Este es el resultado que me devuelve actualmente:

```
[
 {
    "id": "1",
    "dia": "1",
    "conteo1": "779",
    "conteo2": "956",
    "mes": "Abril",
    "clave_comun": "1002"
 },
 {
    "id": "2",
    "dia": "2",
    "conteo1": "696",
    "conteo2": "826",
    "mes": "Mayo",
    "clave_comun": "1002"
 },
 {
    "id": "3",
    "dia": "3",
    "conteo1": "698",
    "conteo2": "772",
    "mes": "Junio",
    "clave_comun": "1002"
 }
]
```

Esto es más o menos lo que debería obtener, creo.

```
    [
        {
            "mes": "Abril",
            "parametros": [ 
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "dia": "1",
                            "conteo1": "779",
                            "conteo2": "956",
                            "clave_comun": "1002"
                        }
            ]
        },
        {
            "mes": "Mayo",
            "parametros": [ 
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "dia": "1",
                            "conteo1": "779",
                            "conteo2": "956",
                            "clave_comun": "1002"
                        }
            ]
        },
        {
            "mes": "Junio",
            "parametros": [ 
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "dia": "1",
                            "conteo1": "779",
                            "conteo2": "956",
                            "clave_comun": "1002"
                        }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Y cuál es el resultado que tienes de momento? Quizás solo tengas que recorrer esos datos de una manera en concreto...

Comment: Acabo de editar y actualizar la cuestión con la respuesta JSON actual.

Comment: Tanto el json creado como los resultados de la consulta se pueden recorrer para crear esa tabla por ejemplo en html, lo que no queda claro es cómo intentas crear la tabla y cual es el problema al mostrarla.

Comment: Creo que el problema principal es que no tienes claro la forma final en que deban ser leídos los datos, definiendo eso ya resolverlas el problema. Por otra parte, la forma en que llenas el array (en el `foreach`) es redundante, no necesitas poner a mano los nombres de las claves, siendo que son los mismos nombres de las columnas. Tampoco logro entender del todo la lógica que implementas, quizá haya redundancia en ella ¿? Puede que el `foreach` sobre si te organizas mejor. Tampoco entiendo el sentido de usar `FOUND_ROWS` ....

Comment: @Carmen - pretendo mostrar el array en un NgFor en Angular

Comment: he vuelto a editar de nuevo para plasmar el resultado deseado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado que solicitas se puede obtener al recorrer los resultados de la consulta, los cuales deben de estar ordenados por mes.

Para ello se establece una variable mes que registra si estamos cambiando de mes al recorrer los resultados para si cambia el mes crear un nuevo objeto y almacenar en él los correspondientes parámetros:

```
$arrayRB4 = []; $mes = ""; $n = -1;
foreach($bucle_RB4 as $itemRB4) {
    if ($mes != $itemRB4['mes']) {
        $mes = $itemRB4['mes'];
        $n++;
        $arrayRB4[$n]["mes"] = $mes;
        $arrayRB4[$n]["parametros"] = array();

    } 
        $array_auxiliar= array(
            "id"        => $itemRB4['id'],
            "dia"       => $itemRB4['dia'],
            "conteo1"   => $itemRB4['conteo1'],
            "conteo2"   => $itemRB4['conteo2'], 
            "clave_comun"       => $itemRB4['clave_comun']
            );
        array_push($arrayRB4[$n]["parametros"],$array_auxiliar);

}
$arrayRB4JSON = json_encode($arrayRB4);
echo $arrayRB4JSON;
```

Ejemplo:

```
//Ejemplo de valores obtenidos en la consulta
$bucle_RB4 = array(
    array("id"=>1, "dia"=>1, "conteo1"=>"a", "conteo2"=>"b", "mes"=>"abril", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>2, "dia"=>2, "conteo1"=>"b", "conteo2"=>"c", "mes"=>"abril", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>3, "dia"=>3, "conteo1"=>"c", "conteo2"=>"d", "mes"=>"abril", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>4, "dia"=>4, "conteo1"=>"d", "conteo2"=>"e", "mes"=>"abril", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>5, "dia"=>5, "conteo1"=>"e", "conteo2"=>"f", "mes"=>"abril", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>6, "dia"=>1, "conteo1"=>"a", "conteo2"=>"b", "mes"=>"mayo", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>7, "dia"=>2, "conteo1"=>"b", "conteo2"=>"c", "mes"=>"mayo", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>8, "dia"=>3, "conteo1"=>"c", "conteo2"=>"d", "mes"=>"mayo", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>9, "dia"=>4, "conteo1"=>"d", "conteo2"=>"e", "mes"=>"mayo", "clave_comun"=>1002),
    array("id"=>10, "dia"=>5, "conteo1"=>"e", "conteo2"=>"f", "mes"=>"mayo", "clave_comun"=>1002)
);
```

Resultado de `echo $arrayRB4JSON;`

```
[{"mes":"abril","parametros":[{"id":1,"dia":1,"conteo1":"a","conteo2":"b","clave_comun":1002},{"id":2,"dia":2,"conteo1":"b","conteo2":"c","clave_comun":1002},{"id":3,"dia":3,"conteo1":"c","conteo2":"d","clave_comun":1002},{"id":4,"dia":4,"conteo1":"d","conteo2":"e","clave_comun":1002},{"id":5,"dia":5,"conteo1":"e","conteo2":"f","clave_comun":1002}]},{"mes":"mayo","parametros":[{"id":6,"dia":1,"conteo1":"a","conteo2":"b","clave_comun":1002},{"id":7,"dia":2,"conteo1":"b","conteo2":"c","clave_comun":1002},{"id":8,"dia":3,"conteo1":"c","conteo2":"d","clave_comun":1002},{"id":9,"dia":4,"conteo1":"d","conteo2":"e","clave_comun":1002},{"id":10,"dia":5,"conteo1":"e","conteo2":"f","clave_comun":1002}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

El **JSON** que te está imprimiendo es correcto, porque así lo estás estructurando tal cual te lo está mostrando.

Para obtener el resultado que tú mencionas tu código tendría que lucir de la siguiente manera:

```
$clave       = "1002";
$resulRB4    = ClaseTike::consultaListado($clave);
$bucle_RB4   = $resulRB4[0];
$contadorRB4 = count($bucle_RB4);
$arrayRB4    = [];
foreach ($bucle_RB4 as $itemRB4):
    $arrayRB4[] = array ("mes"        => $itemRB4['mes'],
                         "parametros" => array (
                             "id"          => $itemRB4['id'],
                             "dia"         => $itemRB4['dia'],
                             "conteo1"     => $itemRB4['conteo1'],
                             "conteo2"     => $itemRB4['conteo2'],
                             "clave_comun" => $clave,
                         ),
    );
endforeach;
$arrayRB4JSON = json_encode($arrayRB4);
echo $arrayRB4JSON;
```

Básicamente el dato de **mes** lo dejas tal cual, creas un segundo dato llamado **parámetros** y a su valor le asignas un **array**, dentro de este metes el resto de los datos y obtendrás el resultado esperado.